# Bootstrap 3 unaligned left margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html, margins

I am using bootstrap 3 and noticed that my left margin gets indented little by little for each row.

Here's a snapshot depicted the issue I'm having, [please check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtDem.jpg)

The code looks something like this for the first two rows in the image:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-toolbar well" role="toolbar">
                    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div id="accordion2" class="panel panel-default">
```

Comment: If you could recreate the issue on jsfiddle I could help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a div inside a div and bootstrap applies a margin or padding (I forgot which one) to it.

test this out : In your style.css or equivelant do this :

```
.nopadtest{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

apply that class to your div's and see what happens. On a side note, you never closed any of the div's ! so you keep putting them in each other.